# The contraction of a symmetric tensor $S_{\mu\nu}$ with another tensor $A^{\mu\nu}$ is $0$, prove that $A^{\mu\nu}$ is antisymmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, physics, tensor-products, symmetric-matrices

Is well known that if $S_{\mu\nu}$ is a symmetric tensor and $A^{\mu\nu}$ is an antisymmetric tensor:
$$S_{\mu\nu}A^{\mu\nu}=0.$$
I want to prove or disprove that if
$$S_{\mu\nu}A^{\mu\nu}=0,$$
and $S_{\mu\nu}$ is symmetric then $A^{\mu\nu}$ must be antisymmetric.

Comment: Take $S=0$ and $A$ anything. You should probably assume that $S_{\mu\nu}A^{\mu\nu}=0$ for **all** symmetric $S$. Then, you can indeed prove $A$ is skew-symmetric.

Comment: If the answers below worked for you personally, please accept the one you are most satisfied by clicking on the check-mark on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that $S_{μν}A^{μν}=0$ for all symmetric $S$.

Since $S_{μν}A^{μν}=0$ for all symmetric $S$, we can choose $S_{11}=1$ and $S_{\mu\nu}=0$ to all remaining entries of $S$. Then it follows from $S_{μν}A^{μν}=0$ that
$$\boxed{A^{11}=0}.$$

Now, choose  $S_{12}=S_{21}=1$ and $S_{\mu\nu}=0$ to all remaining entries of $S$. Then it follows from $S_{μν}A^{μν}=0$ that
$$A^{12}+A^{21}=0\implies\boxed{A^{12}=-A^{21}}.$$

Repeating this procedure to all remaining entries of $S$, we show that
$$\boxed{A^{\mu\nu}=-A^{\nu\mu}}.$$

This means that $A$ is antisymmetric.

Answer (score 2):

Take $S_{\mu\nu} = v_\mu w_\nu + w_\mu v_\nu$, where the numerical values $v_\mu$ and $w_\nu$ are arbitrarily given. Then $$S_{\mu\nu}A^{\mu\nu} = 0$$ reads $$A^{\mu\nu}v_\mu w_\nu = -A^{\mu\nu}w_\mu v_\nu,$$and relabeling indices in the right side yields $$A^{\mu\nu}v_\mu w_\nu = -A^{\nu\mu}v_\mu w_\nu.$$The arbitrariety of $v$ and $w$ now implies that $A^{\mu\nu} = -A^{\nu\mu}$.

In more detail: for fixed indices $\alpha$ and $\beta$, let $v_\mu = \delta_{\mu\alpha}$ and $w_\nu = \delta_{\nu\beta}$ to obtain $A^{\alpha\beta} = -A^{\beta\alpha}$, and then relabel $\alpha$ and $\beta$ back to $\mu$ and $\nu$.

(I think some people in physics call this sort of implication the "quotient theorem" for tensors.)